# Is the inequality $p_{q}<(r^{4q}-2)/(r^{2q+1}+1)$ true?

Tags: number-theory

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let $p_{q}<r^{q}$ be the sequence of prime numbers.

Is this inequality true?

$$p_{q}<(r^{4q}-2)/(r^{2q+1}+1)$$

for all $q>5$

I have no idea to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have $r_q<r^q$. All you have to do is show that
$$
r^q\le\frac{r^{4q}-2}{r^{2q+1}+1},
$$
which is pretty obvius, since the rifht hand side growts like $r^{2q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{r^{4q}-2}{r^{2q+1}+1}>\frac{r^{4q}}{2r^{2q+1}}=\frac{r^{2q}}{2r}>r^{q}>p_{q}.$$